# check if id from one table exists in another

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have two tables Activities and Sources. I want to check if IdSource from Sources, which is primary key, is found in the column Sources from table Activities. 
I did something like

```
private int nrSource {get;set;}
nrSource=(int)activitiesTableAdapter.ScalarQuery();
if (nrSource>0)
{
MessageBox.Show();
}
```

And the ScalarQuery method is something like select count (*) from Activities where exists (select * from Sources where Sources.IdSource=Activities.Sources).

I get an error where I make the cast: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the full error message, in the details of the error message you will see what object is being referenced, that is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

In the first place I would change your query to something like this:

```
select count (*) 
from Activities a
where exists (select * from Sources s where s.IdSource= a.Sources)
```

And if Activities.Sources is nullable and is a foreign key to Sources.IdSource, you could simply use:

```
select count (*) 
from Activities a
where a.Sources IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: nrSource=0. What to initialize it with?

Comment: That means no Activies exist in Sources table.